# Why does the Java compiler 11 use invokevirtual to call private methods?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, javac, java-11

When compiling the code below with the Java compiler from OpenJDK 8, the call to `foo()` is done via an `invokespecial`, but when OpenJDK 11 is used, an `invokevirtual` is emitted.

```java
public class Invoke {
  public void call() {
    foo();
  }

  private void foo() {}
}
```

Output of `javap -v -p` when `javac` 1.8.0_282 is used:

```
  public void call();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #2      // Method foo:()V
         4: return
```

Output of `javap -v -p` when `javac` 11.0.10 is used:

```
  public void call();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokevirtual #2      // Method foo:()V
         4: return
```

I don't get why `invokevirtual` is used here since there cannot be an override of `foo()`.

After digging a bit it seems that the purpose of `invokevirtual` on private methods is to allow nested classes to call private methods from the outer class. So I tried the code below:

```java
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Build a Derived such that Derived.getValue()
    // somewhat "exists".
    System.out.println(new Derived().foo());
  }

  public static class Base {

    public int foo() {
      return getValue() + new Nested().getValueInNested();
    }

    private int getValue() {
      return 24;
    }

    private class Nested {

      public int getValueInNested() {
        // This is getValue() from Base, but would
        // invokevirtual call the version from Derived?
        return getValue();
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Derived extends Base {

    // Let's redefine getValue() to see if it is picked by the
    // invokevirtual from getValueInNested().
    private int getValue() {
      return 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling this code with 11, we can see in the output of `javap` that `invokevirtual` is used both in `foo()` and in `getValueInNested()`:

```
  public int foo();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0

         // ** HERE **
         1: invokevirtual #2  // Method getValue:()I
         4: new           #3  // class Test$Base$Nested
         7: dup
         8: aload_0
         9: invokespecial #4  // Method Test$Base$Nested."<init>":(LTest$Base;)V
        12: invokevirtual #5  // Method Test$Base$Nested.getValueInNested:()I
        15: iadd
        16: ireturn
```

```
  public int getValueInNested();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #1  // Field this$0:LTest$Base;

         // ** HERE **
         4: invokevirtual #3  // Method Test$Base.getValue:()I
         7: ireturn
```

All of this is a bit confusing and raises some questions:

- Why `invokevirtual` is used to call private methods? Is there a use case where replacing it by an `invokespecial` would not be equivalent?
- How does the call to `getValue()` in `Nested.getValueInNested()` not pick the method from `Derived` since it is called via `invokevirtual`?

Comment: Since [JEP 181](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181), `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` can call private methods of classes and interfaces respectively. This is to avoid overcomplicating already non-trivial access rules of `invokespecial`. `invokevirtual` is not better or worse than `invokespecial` performance-wise - it's just a modern way of calling private methods, whether of the same class or of a nestmate. And yes, it's possible to replace it back to `invokespecial` - there is even a `javac` flag for this: `-XDdisableVirtualizedPrivateInvoke`

Comment: @apangin I have the feeling that the `invokeinterface` instruction (its existence as a whole) and perhaps even the distinction between `Methodref` and `InterfaceMethodref` in the constant pool, is even more an unnecessary complication. The clean separation between interface methods and non-interface methods at the invocation instruction was lost in Java 8 already and private methods in interfaces and nest classes made it even more blurry. And the optimizations that an interpreter could do with that distinction became irrelevant even long before Java 8.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This was done as part of https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181: Nest-Based Access Control, so that the JVM can allow access to private methods from nested classes.

Before that change, the compiler would have to generate a package-protected synthetic method in the `Base` class, which the nested class invokes. That synthetic method would in turn call the private method in the `Base` class. The feature in Java 11 enhances the JVM to allow that without the compiler having to generate a synthetic method.

Concerning the point on whether `invokevirtual` will call the method in the `Derived` class, the answer is no. The private method is still not subject to [method selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.6) of the runtime class (this has never changed):

> During execution of an `invokeinterface` or `invokevirtual` instruction, a method is *selected* with respect to (i) the run-time type of the object on the stack, and (ii) a method that was previously resolved by the instruction. The rules to select a method with respect to a class or interface C and a method m<sub>R</sub> are as follows:

> > 1. If m<sub>R</sub> is marked `ACC_PRIVATE`, then it is the selected method.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment *"Would it be valid to still use invokespecial if the private method is called from the method owner class and use invokevirtual if it is called from a nested class?"*

As Holger mentioned, yes it is valid, but based on the [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181), I'm guessing a decision was made to switch to `invokevirtual` for simplicity (I cannot confirm this though, it's just a guess):

> With the change to the access rules, and with suitable adjustments to byte code rules, we can allow simplified rules for generating invocation bytecodes:

> > - invokespecial for private nestmate constructors,
> > - invokevirtual for private non-interface, nestmate instance methods,
> > - invokeinterface for private interface, nestmate instance methods; and
> > - invokestatic for private nestmate, static methods

Another interesting note from [JDK-8197445 : Implementation of JEP 181: Nest-Based Access Control](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8197445):

> Traditionally, `invokespecial` is used to invoke `private` members, though `invokevirtual` also has this capability. Rather than perturb the complex rules about supertypes enforced by `invokespecial`, we require invocations of `private` methods in a different class to use `invokevirtual`.

Comment: But there was no need to change the behavior for cases where caller and method are in the same class.

Comment: Would it be valid to still use invokespecial if the private method is called from the method owner class and use invokevirtual if it is called from a nested class?

Comment: @Julien yes, [the purpose of `invokespecial` hasn’t changed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial): “Invoke instance method; direct invocation of instance initialization methods and **methods of the current class** and its supertypes”.

Answer (score 9):

#### Top-Up To an already good answer

Thought it would be proper to add some more info to the answer already provided and accepted, although it isn't strictly necessary, it may help broaden the understanding, hence it's within SO users best interest.

#### Nest-Based Access Control

In earlier versions, before Java 11, as already pointed out by [@m-a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064245/m-a) in the accepted answer, the compiler would need
to create *bridge methods* to allow classes to access each other's private members in such
conditions. These *accessibility-broadening bridge methods* gets called in the execution context, where the compiler inserts code into a running program.

Doing this **increases both the size of the deployed applications and increases the complexity, plus it makes it harder to understand what is going on behind the scenes.**

**Java 11** introduced the concept of *nest-based access control*.
Along with the notion of *nestmates* and the associated access rules within the JVM,
this allows classes and interfaces to be nested within each other.

Nested types can be *private* fields, methods, and constructors.

Using the updated reflection API you can now query for information about the
nest-based access control functionality.

**Some New Goodness in Java 11**

The `getNestHost()` method is used to get the name of nest host and the `isNestmateOf()` method
can be used to check whether a class is a *nestmate*.
Also, `getNestMembers()` method returns an array of nest members.

Here is a link to a generic example, courtesy of Baeldung.com, [Nest Based Access Control](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nest-based-access-control) that makes the benefits stand out pretty well IMHO.

Notice that there isn't a compiler generated bridging method in the disassembled code. Also, the Inner class can now make a direct call to the outerPrivate() method in the example linked to above.